# Does a dual boot with Windows make Ubuntu more prone to "breaking"?

Tags: dual-boot

I've been using Ubuntu as my primary OS on my laptop, but I've been forced to dual boot it with Windows because sometimes I'm required to use software that only works on Windows. I've had a fair share of problems with Ubuntu (things like invalid arch independent ELF magic, etc.) using this setup. Is the number of problems Ubuntu has somehow related to Windows' presence?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what the problem is but very unlikely, as the partitions are separate. I'll assume you installed windows and then installed linux, as it doesn't work so gracefully the other way around with the windows boot loader.

Comment: I suppose you're right. I just fixed an invalid arch independent ELF magic error - it's odd though. Ubuntu ran perfectly for months, then one day I can't boot up.